# Parachute in vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, velocity, drag

Consider that the earth is vacuum. Consider a person of weight 100 kg is falling from sky with an parachute . He is free falling at height of 3000 m. When will he reach the ground? What would happen if he opens the parachute in diving? Will it work ?

Comment: Nope. :) Parachutes work because they provide a drag resistance, which doesn't exist in vacuum, because there isn't anything to provide the drag.

Comment: Didn't the Apollo astronauts drop [a feather and a hammer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C5_dOEyAfk) on the moon to confirm that they arrive at the same time in vacuum. Similar concept here.

Answer (score 2):

You've assumed that the earth is in vacuum. By that phrase, I think you're mentioning that there's no atmosphere. Then, we can neglect the drag by which the guy attains the terminal velocity (which is about [some 50 m/s](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/JianHuang.shtml)). And, the mass 100 kg isn't necessary, since all objects fall at the same rate <sup>[1]</sup>.

We all know the acceleration due to gravity is about $9.8\ \text{ms}^{-2}$. Though there's a slight variation of $g$ with altitude, we can approximate this to be 9.8 (or even **10** if you wanna have some guess on the time). This means that the velocity is 9.8 m/s after a second, and then 19.6 m/s and so on...

You've assumed the distance to be 3000 m. Using the basic [equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_motion#SUVAT_equations), it's very easy to calculate the time taken for the guy to **crash into ground**. The initial velocity being zero, $t=\sqrt{2s/10}\approx24\ s$...

---

[1]: I've neglected the use of parachute because both the parachute and the guy fall at the same rate ([parachutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachute) won't be useful in the absence of drag) which is already been testified by a historical experiment [by Galileo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies) (or the famous feather & coin)...

Answer (score 1):

A parachute wouldn't work in a vaccum, because of the absence of air. Parachutes work on the principal of prividing more drag, therefore decreacing speed. If there is no drag, a parachute is redundant. A better option would not to jump from 3000m heights in vaccums. ;)

Comment: Can you explain what your answer adds to CrazyBuddy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

NASA has a great website that discusses these issues, because they are also very important for space ships. [Click here.](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/mofall.html)

They didn't calculate $3000~\text{m}$ yet, but I think you might be able to do that yourself.

> [image]